# .NET Core HttpClient - avoid auto redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using .NET Core 2.1 to consume some APIs. In my Startup.cs I configure a named HttpClient like this:

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyApi", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://foo.com");
});
```

I would like to disable the automatic redirect following. I know you can do that when creating a new HttpClient by passing in a SocketsHttpHandler with AllowAutoRedirect = false. But when using the above factory pattern, I'm not seeing where I can configure this as I don't have access to the HttpClient's construction.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `AllowAutoRedirect` property belongs to the `HttpMessageHandler`. When using the `AddHttpClient` approach, you can configure the `HttpMessageHandler` itself using [`ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.configureprimaryhttpmessagehandler). Here's an example of how to use this:

```
services
    .AddHttpClient("MyApi", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://foo.com");
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false
        };
    });
```

This is covered in the official docs: [Configure the HttpMessageHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-the-httpmessagehandler)